# The target MvcBuildViews listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets does not exist in the project, and will be ignored

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity

In TeamCity build I see a bunch (between 80 to 120 or so) lines that look exactly like the following (with only the timestamp changing) and I have no clue what they do or how to resolve them (the build in total succeeds):

> [05:58:44][Step 1/3] The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets (839,131)" does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

Or, in shorter form without the logger's garbage:

> The target "MvcBuildViews" listed in a `BeforeTargets` attribute at `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets` (839,131) does not exist in the project, and will be ignored.

Besides being strange that they appear at all and are repeated over and over, recently somewhere in the middle of the list, there's a large gap in time:

> [05:58:44][Step 1/3] The target "MvcBuildViews" [...]
>   [06:19:38][Step 1/3] The target "MvcBuildViews" [...]

Leading to our builds running in total about 30 minutes as opposed to the "normal" 5 minutes or so.

Googling for this message gave me no hits at all, so I estimate my chances on resolving this to be rather slim, but if anyone has encountered this before and knows what's causing this, I'd be *very* interested to know about a resolution.

This project is build with VS 2010 (yes, we need to update, really), and TeamCity's version is 9.1.3.

PS: hints as to what this warning may entail (apart from apparently related to MVC) and to where to start searching for a solution are of course just as welcome ;)

Comment: Have you seen this Phil Haack post which might be relevant? http://haacked.com/archive/2011/05/09/compiling-mvc-views-in-a-build-environment.aspx/

Comment: @Nanhydrin, I didn't, but it addresses situations that are wrong in your own project file, and this isn't even an MVC project (well, it's a bunch of projects, 50 or so of them are web controls, some normal assembly dlls and 10 or so web services). My error is in MS's own .target file, it seems.

Comment: Have you tried building this locally at the command line using the same version of MSBuild that TeamCity is using? I won't solve the problem but might at least let you replicate it locally. You're building with 2010 locally, but v11.0 as referenced in the error is VS 2012. Could be that TeamCity is targeting a newer version of the framework, MSBuild or the ToolsVersion than your local VS 2010?

Comment: @Nanhydrin, thanks for the tip, but yes, I tried it locally _and_ on another build server, which behaves normal. But you may be right, and the wrong msbuild is being called (I've never been able to map v11, v12 etc to2008,  2010, 2012 etc).

Comment: I've run into this before.  In fact, I'm running into it now, but I can't remember what I did before.  I suggest running msbuild with maximum debug verbosity on both the working and failing machines, and then doing a diff of the output.  That should give you the first point where it breaks down.

Comment: In my case, I gave up and installed VS2015 on the build server, instead of just the Build Tools.  You might try that with VS2010.

Comment: @Bobson, perhaps that would help. In fact, we did install VS2015, but never installed VS2010 (only the build tools). Strangely, the situation seems to happen less frequently, about 1 out of 3 runs 40 min, rest runs around 5 min. Still very strange that the behavior is non-deterministic (it happens even on repeated builds of the same changes).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue with one of my projects.  In my particular scenario, it was caused by a missing 'Target' element in my csproj file.  Adding the following to the bottom of the csproj fixed the issue.

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
  <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
</Target>
```

Comment: Accepting this, though it is too long ago to remember whether it was the cause/solution to my original issue.